# I'm trying to setup pytest and module name not being recognized

Tags: python, django, path, pytest, pytest-django

I'm trying to configure `pytest` for the first time.

When I run the command:

```
python -m pytest
```

I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'Socialmedia.settings.local'; 'Socialmedia.settings' is not a package

pytest-django found a Django project in C:\Users\Alon\PycharmProjects\Socialmedia (it contains manage.py) and added it to the Python path.
If this is wrong, add "django_find_project = false" to pytest.ini and explicitly manage your Python path.
```

pytest file:

```
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = Socialmedia.settings.local
python_files = test_*.py
```

Looks like the error is caused due to `socialmedia` not being recognized.

I tried:

Changing **init** file and adding the module there.

```
import Socialmedia
from Socialmedia import settings
__all__ = [Socialmedia, settings]
```

Moving to another directory from the project to the app.

[the following picture shows how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gj8Ps.png)

Any idea how to make `socialmedia` accessible in this file?

UPDATE:
Solved it by removing `.local` and changing my `test.py` to `test_.py`

Comment: So you have an app dir named `Socialmedia`, and in that dir you have another dir named `settings`, and in that dir you have a python file named `local.py` ?

Comment: Yes, there is a app dir named Socialmedia, and inside that i have a file called settings.py

Comment: If the actual module is named `settings.py`, then what is the `.local` part for?

Comment: actually .local doesn't have anything to do with it. i can simply remove it. the issue starts before settings.py